# How to know that my bluetooth device was removed by pressing "Forget This Device"?

Tags: swift, objective-c, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

1. I did pair bluetooth device using: ***centralManager.connect(peripheral, options: nil)***
2. Killing my application
3. Bluetooth device presented in the Settings -> Bluetooth -> "MY DEVICES" list.
4. By pressing "Forget This Device" in the Settings -> Bluetooth device gets removed from the "MY DEVICES" list.
5. I want to get information that my bluetooth device is not any more paired with iPhone.

How could I get information, that my bluetooth device was removed from the MY DEVICES" list using "Forget This Device"?

#### Connected to selected peripheral:

```
centralManager.connect(peripheral, options: nil)
```

#### In delegate saving identifier:

```
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
    UserDefaults.standart.set(peripheral.identifier, key: "peripheralID")
}
```

#### Retrieving peripherals, that I will not need to do scan once again:

```
let identifier = // Getting identifier from user defaults.
guard let peripheral = centralManager.retrievePeripherals(withIdentifiers: identifiers).first else {
    log("Can not retrieve peripherals", log: .ble, type: .info)
    return
}
centralManager.connect(peripheral, options: nil)
```

Comment: When application is not running here is no any call in the delegate.

Comment: I want to get this information, when my application was not running and user removed BT device from the list.